# Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ generates the standard (product) topology on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

Below is the definition of product topology.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. The product of $X$ and $Y$ , denoted $X$ and $Y$ is the set of ordered pairs given by

$$X \times Y := \{(x,y) \vert x \in X, y \in Y\}. ~~$$

I can let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then let $x \in U$, then $x$ is an interior point of $U$, so $\exists r > 0$, such that $B_r(x) = \{y \vert d(x,y) < r \} \subseteq U$. Therefore, $d(x,y)$ is the generated standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. This is how I thought I will do the problem but cant get it properly.

Can someone help me on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you want to show is that the metric topology generated by open disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same as the product topology generated by open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This amounts to showing that open balls generate the product topology and open rectangles generate the metric topology.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534055/showing-product-topology-on-mathbbr2is-same-as-the-standard-topology-on?rq=1

Comment: Also, careful when you say: "I can let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$." You have two topologies here.

Comment: @tangentbundle This is showing that standard topology is same as product topology but my question is different. Its all about showing that metric topology is similar to standard (product) topology.

Comment: The standard topology is the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. My comment indeed tells you how to show that the metric topology is the same as the standard (product) topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two definitions of the product topology on $\Bbb R^2$, which are equivalent: one is the topology generated by the base

$$\mathcal{B}=\{U \times V: U,V \subseteq \Bbb R \text{ open }\}$$

and another is more abstractly as "the smallest topology that makes both maps $\pi_1,\pi_2: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, defined by $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_2(x,y)=y$, continuous"

I'll use the former, more concrete, view.

Let $O$ be product open in $\Bbb R^2$, and we have to show that $O$ is $d$-open, or equivalently that each $(x_1,x_2) \in O$ is an interior point of $O$ w.r.t. $d$.
So let $(x_1,x_2) \in O$ and by the (first) definition of the product topology we can find $O_1,O_2$ open in $\Bbb R$ such that $x_1 \in O_1$, $x_2 \in O_2$ and $O_1 \times O_2 \subseteq O$. As $O_1$ is open in $\Bbb R$, we find $r_1 >0$ such that $$\{y\in \Bbb R: |x_1 - y| < r_1 \} \subseteq O_1\tag{1}$$ and likewise we have $r_2>0$ such that $$\{y\in \Bbb R: |x_2 - y| < r_2 \} \subseteq O_2\tag{2}$$

Now define $r=\min(r_1,r_2) > 0$, and suppose that $d((y_1,y_2), (x_1, x_2)) < r$. Then $$|x_1 - y_1|^2 = (x_1-y_1)^2 \le d((y_1,y_2), (x_1, x_2))^2 < r^2 \le r_1^2$$

from which it follows (taking square roots) that

$$|x_1 - y_1| < r_1$$ which implies that $y_1 \in O_1$ by $(1)$. A similar reasoning gives us that $y_2 \in O_2$, and so $(y_1, y_2) \in O$. As $(y_1,y_2) \in B_d((x_1,x_2), r)$ was arbitrary we have shown that

$$B_d((x_1,x_2), r) \subseteq O$$ and $(x_1, x_2)$ is indeed an interior point for $O$. All in all this shows that $$\mathcal{T}_{\text{prod}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_d$$

For the other inclusion, we take $O$ $d$-open and show it is product-open, so let $(x_1,x_2) \in O$ again. We need to find $O_1, O_2$ open in $\Bbb R$ such that $(x_1,x_2) \in O_1 \times O_2 \subseteq O$. We know we have $r>0$ such that $$B_d((x_1,x_2), r) \subseteq O\tag{3}$$

Now let $O_1 = \{y \in \Bbb R: |x_1 - y| < \frac{r}{2}\}$ which is open in $\Bbb R$ (it's an open interval/open ball) and similarly is $O_2 = \{y \in \Bbb R: |x_2 - y| < \frac{r}{2}\}$, also open. If $(y_1, y_2) \in O_1 \times O_2$ we know that

$$d((y_1,y_2), (x_1, x_2))^2 = |x_1 - y_1|^2 + |x_2 - y_2|^2 < \frac{r^2}{4} + \frac{r^2}{4} < r^2 $$ which implies (taking roots again)

$$d((y_1,y_2), (x_1, x_2)) < r \text{ and so } (y_1, y_2) \in B_d((x_1,x_2), r) \text{ and by (3) we get } (y_1, y_2) \in O$$

and so $O_1 \times O_2 \subseteq O$ as required.

All in all, this shows $$\mathcal{T}_d \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\text{prod}}$$

and we have equality of topologies.

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I took a look at wat u did. I have some questions: wats $B_d$ you defined? Also, why did you choose $y$ to be fixed while defining $O_1$ and $O_2$ ? Also, what's $r$ and $r_1$ ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun For a metric space $(X,d)$, $B_d(x,r) = \{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$ is the open ball in the metric $d$ wit centre $x$ and radius $r>0$, In the topology on $(X,d)$ a set $O$ is open iff $\forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B_d(x,r)\subseteq O$, which is what I use repeatedly when reasoning about $\mathcal{T}_d$. And $r_1$ and $r$ are radii (real positive numbers).

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun The $y_i$ vary, the $x_i$ are fixed temporarily.

Comment: I knew abt $B_d(x,r)$ but didn't understand the way u defined it. but right now it makes sense n its clear. Appreciate your help man.